# How to query firestore db and return filtered values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an app and i would like to query Firebase document. Allow me to digress.

I have this path: 'dev_env/school/applications/schoolx'. Schoolx represents schools which are documents under the applications collection as documents. Now each document have fields and their respective values, and there is a field with the name school_id and it has a different value for each school respectively. My aim is to query the documents for any school with a specific school_id and display it. The problem is that after deploying the function and use POSTMAN to test it using the endpoint of my Firebase app, it returns null. I followed the direction of the Firebase docs.

The code i wrote is below, please point out my mistake and provide a possible correction. I had to make this clear for all to understand and help.

```
export const completeRegistration = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    // response.send('expired.');

    // Defining school_collection references.
    const schoolRef = fsRef
      .collection('dev_env')
      .doc('school')
      .collection('school_collections');

    // Defining application reference
    const appRef = fsRef
      .collection('dev_env')
      .doc('school')
      .collection('applications');

    const schoolId = request.body.schId;

    console.log(schoolId);

    // Filtering the collection to get egt a specific document with its data.
    await appRef
      .where('school_id', '==', schoolId)
      .get()
      .then((snap) => {
       // console.log(snap.docs);
        if (snap.empty) {
          console.log("Couldn't find a matching document");
          response.status(403).send('School not found');
        } else {
          snap.forEach(school => {
            const data = school.data();
            console.log(school.id, '=>', data);
            // Updating a field when query returns true/false.
            const schoolInfo = {
              school_name: data.school_name,
              school_address: data.school_address,
              school_city: data.school_city,
              school_state: data.school_state,
              school_phone_number: data.school_phone_number,
            };
            schoolRef
              .doc(schoolId)
              .set(schoolInfo)
              .then(() => {
                const updateInfo = {
                  school_reg_completed: true,
                };
                appRef
                  .doc(schoolInfo.school_name)
                  .update(updateInfo)
                  .then(() => {
                    response.status(200).send('School registration complete');
                  })
                  .catch(() => {
                    console.log('Error ecountered while updating apllication');
                  });
              })
              .catch(() => {
                console.log('Adding school to school_collection failed.');
              });
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Operation failed');
        response.status(403).send('failed');
      });
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Could you please share a visual of the structure of your database ? It is a bit confusing between the description and the code you provided. Also you seem to be having a lot of nested queries which is not advisable. It's better to make a query to get all the docs matching the field you want, then from there in your code grab more specific fields and filtering etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i have been feeling "under the weather" for a while. I  will do as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to spot my errors and made the following corrections. It solved it for me. The code is below:

```
export const completeRegistration = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    // response.send('expired.');

    // Defining school_collection references.
    const schoolRef = fsRef
      .collection("dev_env")
      .doc("schools")
      .collection("school_collections");

    // Defining application reference
    const appRef = fsRef
      .collection("dev_env")
      .doc("schools")
      .collection("applications");

    const schoolId = request.body.schId;

    console.log(schoolId);

    // Filtering the collection to get a specific document with its data.
    const task = appRef.where("school_id", "==", schoolId);
    task
      .get()
      .then(async (snap) => {
        // console.log(snap.docs);
        if (snap.empty) {
          console.log("Couldn't find a matching document");
          response.status(403).send("School not found");
        } else {
          snap.forEach(async (school) => {
            const data = school.data();
            console.log(school.id, "=>", data);

            // Updating a field when query returns true/false.

            const schoolInfo = {
              school_name: data.school_name,
              school_address: data.school_address,
              school_city: data.school_city,
              school_state: data.school_state,
              school_phone_number: data.school_tel,
              school_email: data.school_email,
              school_id: data.school_id,
              no_staff: 0,
              no_student: 0,
              school_website: data.school_website,
            };
            console.log(schoolInfo);
            await schoolRef
              .doc(schoolId)
              .set(schoolInfo)
              .then(function () {
                console.log("School sucessfully added");
              });

            const updateInfo = {
              school_reg_completed: true,
            };
            await appRef
              .doc(schoolInfo.school_name)
              .update(updateInfo)
              .then(() => {
                response.status(200).send("School registration complete");
              });
            response.status(200).send("Successful");
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Operation failed");
        response.status(403).send("failed");
      });
  }
);
```